# Python keyboard module freeze/not working when a thread is started

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard

This is my first time to do Python program and I do a simple Python program as below but it freeze at the point keyboard.is_pressed() call, it was unable to print my testing message "loop 1 time now", this means pressing any key will give no response and this function call does not return at all, even Ctrl-C does not able to break the program and back to command prompt control.

```
import threading
import asyncio
import time
import keyboard

flagkeypress = False
keycode = 'a'
flagserverconnected = False

def task1():
    print("Connecting to server")
    asyncio.run(connect2svr())
    print("task1 ended")


async def connect2svr():
    global flagkeypress
    global keycode
    global flagserverconnected

    try:
        print("Connected to server")
        flagserverconnected = True

        keeploopBLE = True
        while keeploopBLE:
            if flagkeypress == True:
                flagkeypress = False
                if keycode == 'q':
                    for k in range(14, 19):
                        sk="##SP"+ f"{k:02}"
                        print(sk)
                        await asyncio.sleep(1)
                if keycode == ']':
                    keeploopBLE = False
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")


print("Start of my main program")
# Create threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1)
# Start threads
t1.start()

keeploop = True
while keeploop:
    print("\nOptions: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time\n")
    print("Press key for command:")

    waitkey = True
    while waitkey:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('t'):
            my_kevent = keyboard.read_event()
            keyn = my_kevent.name
            print(f"key {keyn} is pressed, program going to end")
            keycode = ']'
            flagkeypress = True
            waitkey = False
            keeploop = False
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            my_kevent = keyboard.read_event()
            keyn = my_kevent.name
            print(f"key {keyn} is pressed")
            keycode = 'q'
            flagkeypress = True
            waitkey = False
        print("loop 1 time now")
        time.sleep(0.2)

    time.sleep(0.5)
print("Main program ended")
t1.join()
```

If I removed the task1 thread, the python code simplified as below, then it works as I expect, "loop 1 time now" is printed continuously.  What is the root cause the exists of thread task1 affect the keyboard module API become not working?  But so far I cannot 100% say the freeze is caused by the exists of thread task1, as I have another version before that task1 exists and it still working if I remove a waiting while loop, but I didn't save that version before I further simplify it to this 2 versions.

```
import asyncio
import time
import keyboard

flagkeypress = False
keycode = 'a'

print("Start of my main program")
keeploop = True
while keeploop:

    print("\nOptions: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time\n")
    print("Press key for command:")

    waitkey = True
    while waitkey:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('t'):
            my_kevent = keyboard.read_event()
            keyn = my_kevent.name
            print(f"key {keyn} is pressed, program going to end")
            keycode = ']'
            flagkeypress = True
            waitkey = False
            keeploop = False
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            my_kevent = keyboard.read_event()
            keyn = my_kevent.name
            print(f"key {keyn} is pressed")
            keycode = 'q'
            flagkeypress = True
            waitkey = False
        print("loop 1 time now")
        time.sleep(0.2)

    time.sleep(0.5)
print("Main program ended")
```

output:

```
C:\Projects\pytest1>python pytest3.py
Start of my main program

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key q is pressed
loop 1 time now

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key q is pressed
loop 1 time now

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key q is pressed
loop 1 time now

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key q is pressed
loop 1 time now

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key q is pressed
loop 1 time now

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key q is pressed
loop 1 time now

Options: [Q]=Get Version, [T]=Get Time, [P]=Start/End Get GPS Time

Press key for command:
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
loop 1 time now
key t is pressed, program going to end
loop 1 time now
Main program ended
```

Comment: You might want to learn some Python fundamentals before getting into async. You may find the *keyboard* module unreliable depending on your platform.

Comment: I agree with @CtrlZ, but if you really wanted to do this, it is probably inefficient to use `keyboard.is_pressed()` in a loop. Take a look at `keyboard.add_hotkey()`, so whenever you press a certain key, it calls a function. For example, `keyboard.add_hotkey('q', getVersion)`, so whenever you press q, it calls the function `getVersion()`.

Comment: Thx for comment, and I found add_hotkey() with callback do works fine, and will not behave freeze like is_pressed() do.  But it still exhibit a small problem that the keyboard buffer is not cleared and those pressed keys pops out when I call input() or exit the program, not sure how can I clear those key buffer/event.  It is still interesting to know why is_pressed() read_event() freeze when another thread is launched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this using `keyboard.add_hotkey()` with a callback function. It works and will not freeze like the `keyboard.is_pressed()` is doing.  Also I tested the `read_key()` and `read_event()`, which also exhibit the freeze and not return behavior.  Anyway, only `add_hotkey()` is working.

But `add_hotkey()` is not working as I expected. The key buffer input is not cleared, and there is no way to clear it in the keyboard module APIs.  Those pressed keys will pop out when my program ends or when `input()` is called.  So this is absolutely not able to fulfill my basic requirement.

I tried another module - `pynput`. This module has no freeze/not return problem too; however, it has the same problem of being unable to clear the key input. All pressed keys will pop out when my program ends.

Finally I tried the `msvcrt` module (Microsoft). The `msvcrt.kbhit()` and `msvcrt.getch()` are working perfectly like that in c language.  So the `msvcrt` module perfectly fulfilled my requirement and is working perfectly with multithreading with asyncio functions in thread.

My conclusion is msvcrt's key API is the most stable and bug free; others will lack key buffer clear capability and that is a big defect. Of course the biggest defects are in the keyboard module which is full of bugs.